# what is the synchronise function for mac mps?

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision

I have a mac book with M1 MAX and I try to test the performance of the M1MAX neural engine.

I want to ask cpu to wait until the mac Neural engine tasks to finish, what function should I use? I know for CUDA, I can use torch.cuda.synchronize(), but what function is it for torch on m1?

I have the following code:

```
import torch
if torch.has_mps:
    device = torch.device("mps")
else:
    device = torch.device("cpu")

print("using", device, "device")

import time

matrix_size = 32*512

x = torch.randn(matrix_size, matrix_size)
y = torch.randn(matrix_size, matrix_size)

print("***********cpu speed***************")
start = time.time()
result = torch.matmul(x,y)
print(time.time()-start)
print("verify device: ", result.device)


x_mps = x.to(device)
y_mps = y.to(device)
# torch.cuda.synchronize()


for i in range(3):
    print("***********mps speed***************")
    start = time.time()
    result_mps = torch.matmul(x_mps,y_mps)
    # torch.cuda.synchronize()
    print(time.time()-start)
    print("verify device: ", result_mps.device)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe they have recently updated this since the release of PyTorch 2.0. The answer would be to use:

```py
torch.mps.synchronize()
```

Documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/2.0/mps.html

Much similar to the CUDA backend, it "Waits for all kernels in all streams on a MPS device to complete."

Also, you mention that you want to utilize the Apple Neural Engine (ANE). PyTorch uses the Metal Performance Shaders (MPS) backend for Apple Silicon Macs, which utilizes the GPU. As far as I know, there exists no API to utilize the ANE with PyTorch.

The only exception is to use CoreML to compile your models to utilize the ANE.